# What does "dye content 80%" mean on Sigma Aldrich's product page for "Allura Red AC" (aka Red 40)

Tags: organic-chemistry, food-chemistry

Here's a link to the page: 
http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/sial/458848?lang=en&region=US

Why does it say "dye content 80%"? 
Shouldn't it be pure if it's a packaged powder? 
Is it 20% other chemical compounds (e.g. stabilizers)?

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Visit the [help] to learn more about how it works.

Comment: tbh I'd just mail Sigma Aldrich to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many dyes are sold as powders with 80-90 % purity. It is because some dyes are difficult to purify (e.g. they are difficult to crystallize). The remaining 10-20 % are impurities, such as isomers or closely chemically related side-products, but mostly they are "volatile impurities" (i.e. water). For most purposes these impurities do not interfere, so nobody bothers to remove them. Here is MSDS of Allura Red:
http://www.vidhifoodcolour.com/uploads/gallery/14067976084allura_red.pdf